# Remainder in integral form for first-order bivariate Taylor series

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Could someone spell out the remainder in integral form for a first-order bivariate Taylor series?

Univariate Taylor: $ f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \int_a^x (x - t)f''(t) dt $

Bivariate Taylor: $ f(x,y) = f(a, b) + f_x(a,b) (x -a) + f_y(a,b) (y -b) + \int_? \cdots ? $

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x,b) = f(a,b) + f_x(a,b)(x-a) + \int_a^x f_{xx}(s,b)(x-s)\; ds$$
$$f(x,y) - f(x,b) = f_y(x,b)(y-b) + \int_b^y f_{yy}(x,
t)(y-t)\; dt$$
$$f_y(x,b) = f_y(a,b) + \int_a^x f_{xy}(s,b)\; ds$$
So:
$$f(x,y) - f(a,b) = f_x(a,b)(x-a) + f_y(a,b)(y-b) +  \int_a^x f_{xx}(s,b)(x-s)\; ds + \int_a^x f_{xy}(s,b)(y-b)\; ds + \int_b^y f_{yy}(x,t)(y-t)\; dt $$

Comment: Are you sure about the middle integral? the (y - b) factor does not involve the variable of integration...  Also shouldn't it be multiplied by 2?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  Try it with your favourite $f$.

Comment: OK I checked.  I guess an alternative middle term would be $ (x - a) \int_b^y f_{xy}(a,t) dt $ ?